# validating ajax data values

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is it possible to validate if there empty input?

I want to check if data has gotten values from html. If true then should disable button. If not then don't disable button.

This the sample html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <label>email
                <input type="text" name="email" />
            </label>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

thats the sample html

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Submit").click(function(event) {
       Execute();
    });

    function Execute(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: { 'email': $("input[name='email']").val() },
         success: function(res) {
         if (data) {
          $("#Submit").attr("disabled", true);
        $('#success').text(res.response);
    } if (!data) {
    $("#Submit").attr("disabled", false);
    $('#error').text(res.error_msg);
    } else {  // do nothing }
  },
        error: function(resp) {
          alert("failed");
        }
      });
    };

  });
</script>
```

Comment: html code not included

Comment: @GuspanTanadi question updated

Answer (score 0):

U can validate the values before triggering an ajax request. As u can serialize your form data and then validate your required values for the request and if they validate then trigger the ajax call with required data

```
 function Execute(){
 // Contains all the inputs that are present in your form
 var formData = $('form').serializeArray();

 // Validate your values 

 // If values does not matches your requirements, return false with error like

 alert('All required values not filled');return false;


 // If code reaches here, means you have all your required values. 
 // So, making ajax request makes more sense now as it can be executed successfully as values are first validated then ajax is triggered

 $.ajax({
  // Your code for ajax request

 })

}
```

[image: Perform value validation in the loop for any required values]

Comment: if u do make test u will see that after alert if there null input from user. still the button will become disabled. i dont think ajax can do this coz i tried many ways bt not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I just modified your code. Hope it helps you out. Basically ajax call is not called untill you validate youe values and once you validated your values you can proceed with ajax and handling your button state using ajax lifecycle functions ( I don't know the exact term for these (beforeSend, complete, success etc) ) :)

[image]

Comment: Can u show ur code snippet that you are implementing... it will be helpfull

Comment: like my question.  i want submit button to be enabled when no input from user. disable if we got input from user. its validate input before disabling button

Answer (score 0):

LOL it was more easy like this

i got fixed D:)

only Before send was the solution

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Submit").click(function(event) {
       Execute();

    });

    function Execute(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: { 'email': $("input[name='email']").val() },
        beforeSend: function(){ 

        if ($("form input[name='email']").val() == "") {
        alert("Text-field is empty.");
        return false;
            }
        },
         success: function(response) {
         $("#Submit").attr("disabled", true);
    $('#resp').text(response.feedback);
  },
        error: function() {
          alert("failed");
        }
      });
    };

  });
</script>
```